# Is FirstOrDefault/First and OrderByDescending, quicker than LastOrDefault/Last and OrderBy?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I had a LINQ question I wondered if anyone knew the answer to.

Normally if I wanted to find a record ordered by a particular field, such as the 'latest added person' I'd write something like:

```
MyCollection.OrderByDescending(x => x.AddedDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

Recently I picked up some work from another Dev in the team who prefers to write:

```
MyCollection.OrderBy(x => x.AddedDate).LastOrDefault();
```

So my question is this, is ordering descending and selecting the first, quicker or slowing than ordering the other direction and selecting last?

My thoughts are that first would be quicker as it's not needing to iterate over the collection 'as far' when returning an object, but this is more a hunch than anything else!

Comment: Actually yes, do the benchmark i would also like to know the answer.

Comment: Generally the best way to test this is to create a representative sample and try it yourself.

Comment: Which LINQ? To objects? To Entities? To XML?

Comment: Note that the benchmark may well be susceptible to the particular order of the existing data-set. For example, if it is already mostly in Ascending order, then many algorithms will sort it quicker in that direction. Your benchmark should generate multiple sets of random data, to ensure a fair comparison.

Comment: @RB That is true if this is a general question being asked out of interest. However, if the OP has a particular scenario that they are interested in then I'd say the bias should not be factored out. The data should be as representative as possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're using LINQ-to-Objects, the first one will be *marginally* faster. The two sorts will each take the same amount of time*, but you're right in thinking that `FirstOrDefault` is faster than `LastOrDefault`. However, the difference will be negligible compared to the time the sort takes.

(Note that doing a whole sort to take just the top item is far more inefficient than using `Last` over `First`; consider implementing something like MoreLINQ's [`MaxBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) function to get the item you want in `O(n)`, rather than `O(n log n)`, time.)

If you're using LINQ-to-something else (SQL, Entities), it'll probably make no difference at all.

* in general; as RB points out this might not be the case if the data is already ordered to some extent.

Comment: +1 for suggesting implementing MaxBy. Sorting an entire collection just to find the last item when you're concerned about performance is just wrong.

Comment: Also interesting: If you look at the implementation of `LastOrDefault()` vs `LastOrDefault(predicate)`, the latter lacks an optimization (for lists) that the former has. `LastOrDefault()` with no predicate checks to see if it's a list, and then returns the element at Count - 1, so it's very fast.  `LastOrDefault(predicate)` has no such check, so it always iterates over the whole list from the beginning using the `GetEnumerator` and `MoveNext` methods, rather than simply iterating from `Count - i` and taking the first matching element.  No idea why they implemented it that way.

Comment: And if they would simply add the same optimization they added to `LastOrDefault()` (no predicate) to `'LastOrDefault(predicate)`, it could see performance increases of three orders of magnitude. I re-implemented `LastOrDefault(predicate)` with the `IList` optimization, and ran it on a list with ordered integers from 1 to 100,000, searching for `LastOrDefault(x => x == 99999)`, and the run time for 1000 calls was 5548631 ticks, vs only 3214 for the optimized version. What a huge oversight!

Comment: And it's not even like my example is contrived.  If I instead run `LastOrDefault(x => x == 99)` so the matched item is closer to the front of the list, hypothetically giving the one the iterates from the beginning a huge advantage, it's STILL slower!  3,901,861 vs 2,299,578 ticks.

Comment: I guess I'm not the only one who noticed this epic fail.
"This was a longer post than I anticipated when I got up this morning, but I hope the slight differences between implementations – *and the mystery of the unoptimized predicated "Last/LastOrDefault" operators* have made it worth slogging through." https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/29/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-11-first-single-last-and-the-ordefault-versions/